# Downloadable list of all accredited U.S. colleges?

Tags: united-states, databases, accreditation

I am looking for a downloadable list of all accredited U.S. colleges. I have found many options to search databases, but I am looking for a downloadable list, preferably in spreadsheet format such as xls or csv.

Comment: This question seems to an exact definition of a shopping question: _“Shopping” questions, which seek recommendations or lists of individual universities, academic programs, publishers, journals, research topics, or similar as an answer or seek an assessment or comparison of such, are off-topic here_

Comment: Superficially this might appear to be a shopping question, but I don't think this is a shopping question at all, and I vote to reopen. The distinction here is that the OP is looking for a database that contains a list of accredited colleges. They are not looking for recommendations of  colleges. The question can be answered objectively, and in a single answer. They are not looking for a list of answers, they are looking for an answer that links to a list.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's what [you're looking for on the U.S. Dept. of Education page](http://ope.ed.gov/accreditation/GetDownLoadFile.aspx) in CSV/Excel.

Here's the header of the file:

```
  Institution_ID    Institution_Name    Institution_Address Institution_City    Institution_State   Institution_Zip Institution_Phone   Institution_OPEID   Institution_IPEDS_UnitID    Institution_Web_Address Campus_ID   Campus_Name Campus_Address  Campus_City Campus_State    Campus_Zip  Campus_IPEDS_UnitID Accreditation_Type  Agency_Name Agency_Status   Program_Name    Accreditation_Status    Accreditation_Date_Type Periods Last Action
```

Comment: Geez, I was all over their site and couldn't find that. Thanks!

Comment: No "Date founded" though...